# Find the number of increasing sub sequence

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I want to find the numbers of increasing subsequence in an array and I came across a Binary index tree which provide us `O(log n)` solution.

I can't understand the code used for BIT:

```
void madd(int& a, int b)
{
    a += b;
}

// fenwick code
void update(int i, int x)
{
    for (++i; i < MAX_N; i += i & -i) madd(ft[i], x);
}

int query(int i)
{
    int s = 0;
    for (++i; i > 0; i -= i & -i) madd(s, ft[i]);
    return s;
}

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    dp[i] = 1 + query(H[i] - 1); // H[i] contains the our number array

    update(H[i], dp[i]);
}
```

Please help me to understand it.
Thank you

Comment: Would help to know what `ft`, `dp`, and `H` are.

Comment: @ScottHunter   `ft` is an empty which is used for making `BIT` tree and `H` is our original array and `dp` is used to store the result

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what parts of the code you don't understand? Or do you have issues with an algorithm itself? As of now, it seems to be too broad.

Comment: @user2040251 how can we use BIT in finding the increasing number of increasing sub sequence , according to BIT , tree is made on the basics of the fact that every number can be expressed in the power of 2 , so how it would be useful in this context , please help me to understand the algorithm better

Answer (score 2):

The idea of the algorithm is rather simple:

1. Let's create an array `f`, where `f[i]` is the number of increasing subsequences that has `i` as a last element. Initially it is filled with zeros.
2. Let's iterate over all elements of the initial array and update `f` values. If the current element is `h`, then we can add it to all increasing subsequences that have the last element less than `h` or create a new subsequence that contains only this number. That's why `dp[i] = sum(f[j]) + 1`, where `0 <= j < h`.

BIT can be used to find a sum on a prefix of the array and update one element efficiently(it is required for the step 2), that's why it is used to store `f` values.

Comment: could you explain how the tree is formed and what about query function how it is working

Comment: @user4324674 I would recommend reading an article on binary indexed trees(for example, this one: http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees).

Comment: @user4324674 What questions exactly do you have?

Comment: how the tree is formed in terms of if we have to find the numbers of increasing as we are calculating the sum of frequency for forming a tree

Comment: @user4324674 To understand how the BIT works in this particular problem, imagine that it is a black box that "magically" finds the sum on a prefix and updates one element. To understand how the BIT itself works, forget about counting increasing subsequences(think about sum/update operations) and refer to the article.